# Can not reduce size of Switch in android

Tags: android, android-layout, switchcompat

I have implemented a custom switch (like iOS) in android. It's working perfectly in xhdpi devices (Nexus 4, moto g3). But can't reduce the track width of switch in Nexus S. its too lengthy.

**custom_switch_thumb**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_checked="true">
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle"
        android:visible="true"
        android:dither="true"
        android:useLevel="false">
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#66AAFF00"
            android:endColor="#6600FF00"
            android:angle="270"/>
        <corners
            android:radius="20dp"/>
        <size
            android:width="30dp"
            android:height="30dp" />
        <stroke
            android:width="4dp"
            android:color="#0000ffff"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_checked="false">
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle"
        android:visible="true"
        android:dither="true"
        android:useLevel="false">
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#ff0000"
            android:endColor="#ff0000"
            android:angle="270"/>
        <corners
            android:radius="20dp"/>
        <size
            android:width="30dp"
            android:height="30dp" />
        <stroke
            android:width="4dp"
            android:color="#0000ffff"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

**custom_switch_track**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"
android:visible="true"
android:dither="true"
android:useLevel="false">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#27170432"
    android:endColor="#27170432"
    android:angle="270"/>
<corners
    android:radius="20dp"/>
<size
    android:width="60dp"
    android:height="30dp" />
</shape>
```

**Switch placed in layout**

```
 <Switch
            android:id="@+id/notification_client_switch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:showText="true"
            android:switchMinWidth="0dp"
            android:switchTextAppearance="@style/SwitchTextAppearance"
            android:textOff="@string/no_label"
            android:textOn="@string/yes_label"
            android:thumb="@drawable/custom_switch_selector"
            android:track="@drawable/custom_switch_track" />
```

I have changed track width and Switch "android:switchminwidth" with different values but no effect is found.

Comment: you can use ToggleButton inserted of  Switch.

Comment: @Tijo Joseph you want `Ios` type  `switch` .

Comment: @Ankur1994a Can you please post the code for toggle button

Comment: @Ironman yes. I want iOS type switch

Comment: @TijoJoseph see my answer below.

Comment: @Ankur1994a can we implement it without drawable image. I mean with <shape>

Comment: @TijoJoseph we have require `drawable` Image.

Comment: @TijoJoseph i think we can use it  with shape

Answer (score 0):

Code for toogle Button

```
 <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/notification_client_switch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:background="@drawable/toggleBackground"
            android:checked="true"
            android:textOff=" "
            android:textOn=" " />
```

xml for your drawable toggleBackground

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/on_image"
 android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/off_image"   
android:state_checked="false" />
```